# How to get stable results with TensorFlow, setting random seed

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a neural network multiple times with different parameters in order to calibrate the networks parameters (dropout probabilities, learning rate e.d.). However I am having the problem that running the network while keeping the parameters the same still gives me a different solution when I run the network in a loop as follows:

```
filename = create_results_file()
for i in range(3):
  g = tf.Graph()
  with g.as_default():
    accuracy_result, average_error = network.train_network(
        parameters, inputHeight, inputWidth, inputChannels, outputClasses)
    f, w = get_csv_writer(filename)
    w.writerow([accuracy_result, "did run %d" % i, average_error])
    f.close()
```

I am using the following code at the start of my train_network function before setting up the layers and error function of my network:

```
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

I have also tried adding this code before the TensorFlow graph creation, but I keep getting different solutions in my results output.

I am using an AdamOptimizer and am initializing network weights using `tf.truncated_normal`. Additionally I am using `np.random.permutation` to shuffle the incoming images for each epoch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reproducible results in Tensorflow with tf.set\_random\_seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249811/reproducible-results-in-tensorflow-with-tf-set-random-seed)

Comment: But this question was asked over 2 years earlier, so that question is the duplicate.

Answer (score 50):

Setting the current TensorFlow random seed affects the current default graph only. Since you are creating a new graph for your training and setting it as default (`with g.as_default():`), you must set the random seed within the scope of that `with` block.

For example, your loop should look like the following:

```
for i in range(3):
  g = tf.Graph()
  with g.as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    accuracy_result, average_error = network.train_network(
        parameters, inputHeight, inputWidth, inputChannels, outputClasses)
```

Note that this will use the same random seed for each iteration of the outer `for` loop. If you want to use a different—but still deterministic—seed in each iteration, you can use `tf.set_random_seed(i + 1)`.

Comment: I believe my set_random_seed(1) was already within the g.as_default() block they as it is one of the first lines within the train_network code. Nonetheless I have tried putting the code as in your example, but I am still getting unstable results:

>    accuracy labels  error  
>    0.9805        did run0 2.96916  
>    0.9807        did run1 2.96494  
>    0.9804        did run2 2.95215

Comment: I'm having the same problem. `tensorflow` `0.12.1` setting random seed as specified I see slight differences in probability outputs from run to run.

Comment: The reason will depend on what your function is, but it's likely that small differences in the accuracy calculation are caused by a non-deterministic parallel reduction in ops like `tf.reduce_sum()`. (These ops treat floating point addition as commutative, when in reality it isn't, and changes in the reduction order can lead to slight errors in the result....)

Comment: @mrry, I'm facing a similar error with `DropoutWrapper`. When I keep `keep_prob=1`, I get consistent results. However, different runs give me different values with `keep_prob=0.8`. What could be the reason? I've moved it to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156296/

Answer (score 34):

Backend Setup: `cuda:10.1`, `cudnn: 7`, `tensorflow-gpu: 2.1.0`, `keras: 2.2.4-tf`, and `vgg19` customized model

After looking into the issue of unstable results for tensorflow backend with GPU training and large neural network models based on keras, I was finally able to get reproducible (stable) results as follows:

1. Import only those libraries that would be required for setting seed and initialize a seed value

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
import random

SEED = 0
```

2. Function to initialize seeds for all libraries which might have stochastic behavior

```
def set_seeds(seed=SEED):
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(seed)
    random.seed(seed)
    tf.random.set_seed(seed)
    np.random.seed(seed)
```

3. Activate `Tensorflow` deterministic behavior

```
def set_global_determinism(seed=SEED):
    set_seeds(seed=seed)

    os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'
    os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'
    
    tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
    tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)

# Call the above function with seed value
set_global_determinism(seed=SEED)
```

### Important notes:

- Please call the above code before executing any other code
- Model training might become slower since the code is deterministic, hence there's a tradeoff
- I experimented several times with a varying number of epochs and different settings (including model.fit() with shuffle=True) and the above code gives me reproducible results.

#### References:

1. https://suneeta-mall.github.io/2019/12/22/Reproducible-ml-tensorflow.html
2. https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development
3. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/threading/set_inter_op_parallelism_threads
4. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed?version=nightly

Comment: According to https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-release-notes/rel_19.06.html, setting TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS=1 is enough. It will enable TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC on its own.

Answer (score 17):

Deterministic behaviour can be obtained either by supplying a graph-level or an operation-level seed. Both worked for me. A graph-level seed can be placed with [tf.set_random_seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed). An operation-level seed can be placed e.g, in a variable intializer as in:

```
myvar = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(((10,10)), stddev=0.1, seed=0))
```

Answer (score 17):

**Tensorflow 2.0 Compatible Answer**: For Tensorflow version greater than 2.0, if we want to set the Global Random Seed, the Command used is **`tf.random.set_seed`**.

If we are migrating from **`Tensorflow Version 1.x to 2.x`**, we can use the command, 
**`tf.compat.v2.random.set_seed`**.

Note that **`tf.function`** acts like a re-run of a program in this case.

To set the Operation Level Seed (as answered above), we can use the command, **`tf.random.uniform([1], seed=1)`**.

For more details, refer this [Tensorflow Page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed?version=nightly).

Answer (score 9):

Please add all random seed functions before your code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
tf.random.set_seed(0)
random.seed(0)
np.random.seed(0)
```

I think, some models in TensorFlow are using numpy or the python random function.

Answer (score 9):

It seems as if none of these answers will work due to underlying implementation issues in CuDNN.

You can get a bit more determinism by adding an extra flag

```py
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'  # new flag present in tf 2.0+
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.set_random_seed(SEED)
```

But this still won't be entirely deterministic. To get an even more exact solution, you need use the procedure outlined in this nvidia [repo](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tensorflow-determinism).

Comment: It should be noted that setting `PYTHONHASHSEED` within the process does nothing - it needs to be set outside the process itself, or the script must open a new process with that environmental variable set beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an addition to [Luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed/59722305#59722305) and for TF v2.2.0

```
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf # 2.2.0

SEED = 42
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(SEED)
os.environ['TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC'] = '1'  # TF 2.1
random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
tf.random.set_seed(SEED)
```

Comment: Using `TF_CUDNN_DETERMINISTIC` breaks the notebook with tf 2.3.0 not sure why. This made me debug straight for 2 days in my code! Don't use this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TensorFlow 2 (2.2.0) and I'm running code in JupyterLab. I've tested this in macOS Catalina and in Google Colab with same results. I'll add some stuff to [Tensorflow Support's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed/#60088810) answer.

When I do some training using the model.fit() method I do it in a cell. I do some other stuff in other cells. This is the code I run in the mentioned cell:

```py
# To have same results always place this on top of the cell
tf.random.set_seed(1)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load_data_onehot_grayscale()
model = get_mlp_model_compiled() # Creates the model, compiles it and returns it

history = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train,
                    epochs=30,
                    callbacks=get_mlp_model_callbacks(),
                    validation_split=.1,
                   )
```

This is what I understand:

1. TensorFlow has some random processes that happen at different stages (initializing, shuffling, ...), every time those processes happen TensorFlow uses a random function. When you set the seed using `tf.random.set_seed(1)` you make those processes use it and if the seed is set and the processes don't change the results will be the same.
2. Now, in the code above, if I change `tf.random.set_seed(1)` to go below the line `model = get_mlp_model_compiled()` my results change, I believe it's because `get_mlp_model_compiled()` uses randomness and isn't using the seed I want.
3. Caveat about point 2: if I run the cell 3 times in a row I do get same results. I believe this happens because, in run nº1 `get_mlp_model_compiled()` isn't using TensorFlow's internal counter with my seed. In run nº2 it will be using a seed and all subsequent runs it will be using the seed too so after run nº2 results will be the same.

I might have some information wrong so feel free to correct me.

To understand what's going on you should read [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed), they're not so long and kind of easy to understand.