# How can i get stable results in tensorflow CNN

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, random-seed

I've implemented a CNN in tensor flow following the cs231n class. I wanted to reproduce the same result every time, so i've set the seed where ever it's needed but still my results are not stable. I don't know if it is because of the optimizer that i'm using. Below are the codes that i've written. Please go through it and your help will be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
def train_network(lr, ksz, kst, plsz, plst, bs):
    ksz = np.int(ksz)

    kst = np.int(kst)
    plsz = np.int(plsz)
    plst = np.int(plst)
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    random.seed(0)
    tf.set_random_seed(0)
    np.random.seed(0)
    # tf.set_random_seed(1234)
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        tf.set_random_seed(0)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32, 3])
            y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
            is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)
            # y_out = my_model(X,y,is_training,ksz=np.int(ksz),kst=np.int(kst),plsz=np.int(plsz),plst=np.int(plst))
            # Conv-Relu-BN
            conv1act = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs=X, num_outputs=32, padding='same', kernel_size=ksz, stride=kst,
                                                activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                                weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                    mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0),
                                                biases_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                    mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0))
            bn1act = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inputs=conv1act, is_training=is_training)
            # Conv-Relu-BN
            conv2act = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs=bn1act, num_outputs=64, padding='same', kernel_size=ksz,
                                                stride=kst, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                                weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                    mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0),
                                                biases_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                    mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0))
            bn2act = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inputs=conv2act, is_training=is_training)
            # Conv-Relu-BN
            c3 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs=bn2act, num_outputs=128, padding='same', kernel_size=ksz, stride=kst,
                                          activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                          weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                              mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0),
                                          biases_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                              mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0))
            b3 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inputs=c3, is_training=is_training)
            # Conv-Relu-BN
            c4 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs=b3, num_outputs=256, padding='same', kernel_size=ksz, stride=kst,
                                          activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                          weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                              mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0),
                                          biases_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                              mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0))
            b4 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inputs=c4, is_training=is_training)

            # Maxpool
            maxpool1act = tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d(inputs=b4, stride=plst, kernel_size=plsz)
            # Flatten
            Rsize = maxpool1act.get_shape().as_list()
            # print(Rsize)
            Rsize1 = Rsize[1] * Rsize[2] * Rsize[3]
            flatten1 = tf.reshape(maxpool1act, shape=[-1, Rsize1])
            # FC-Relu-BN
            fc1 = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=flatten1, num_outputs=1024, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                                    weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                        mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0),
                                                    biases_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                        mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0))
            bn3act = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inputs=fc1, is_training=is_training)
            # Output FC 
            y_out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=bn3act, num_outputs=10, activation_fn=None,
                                                      weights_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                          mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0),
                                                      biases_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(
                                                          mode="FAN_AVG", seed=0))
            mean_loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(logits=y_out, onehot_labels=tf.one_hot(y, 10))
            # optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
            optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)

            # batch normalization in tensorflow requires this extra dependency
            extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
            with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
                train_step = optimizer.minimize(mean_loss)

            with tf.device("/cpu:0"):  # "/cpu:0" or "/gpu:0" 
                sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
                print('Training')
                run_model(X, y, mean_loss, is_training, sess, y_out, mean_loss, X_train, y_train, 10, np.int(bs), 100,
                          train_step, True)
                print('Validation')
                loss, val = run_model(X, y, mean_loss, is_training, sess, y_out, mean_loss, X_val, y_val, 1, np.int(bs))
    return 1 - val
```

run model function

```
def run_model(X, y, mean_loss, is_training, session, predict, loss_val, Xd, yd,
              epochs=1, batch_size=64, print_every=100,
              training=None, plot_losses=False):
    # have tensorflow compute accuracy
    # print(predict)
    random.seed(0)
    np.random.seed(0)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predict, 1), y)
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    # shuffle indicies
    train_indicies = np.arange(Xd.shape[0])
    # np.random.shuffle(train_indicies)
    # print(train_indicies)
    training_now = training is not None

    # setting up variables we want to compute (and optimizing)
    # if we have a training function, add that to things we compute
    variables = [mean_loss, correct_prediction, accuracy]
    if training_now:
        variables[-1] = training

    # counter
    iter_cnt = 0
    for e in range(epochs):
        # keep track of losses and accuracy
        correct = 0
        losses = []
        # make sure we iterate over the dataset once
        for i in range(int(math.ceil(Xd.shape[0] / batch_size))):
            # print()
            # generate indicies for the batch
            start_idx = (i * batch_size) % Xd.shape[0]
            idx = train_indicies[start_idx:start_idx + batch_size]

            # create a feed dictionary for this batch
            feed_dict = {X: Xd[idx, :],
                         y: yd[idx],
                         is_training: training_now}
            # get batch size
            actual_batch_size = yd[idx].shape[0]
            # print(actual_batch_size)
            # have tensorflow compute loss and correct predictions
            # and (if given) perform a training step
            loss, corr, _ = session.run(variables, feed_dict=feed_dict)
            # print(np.sum(corr))
            # aggregate performance stats
            losses.append(loss * actual_batch_size)

            correct += np.sum(corr)
            # print(np.sum(corr))
            # print(actual_batch_size)
            # print(np.sum(corr)/float(actual_batch_size))
            # print every now and then
            if training_now and (iter_cnt % print_every) == 0:
                print("Iteration {0}: with minibatch training loss = {1:.3g} and accuracy of {2:.2g}" \
                      .format(iter_cnt, loss, float(np.sum(corr)) / actual_batch_size))
            iter_cnt += 1
        total_correct = float(correct) / Xd.shape[0]
        total_loss = np.sum(losses) / Xd.shape[0]
        print("Epoch {2}, Overall loss = {0:.3g} and accuracy of {1:.3g}" \
              .format(total_loss, total_correct, e + 1))
        if plot_losses:
            plt.plot(losses)
            plt.grid(True)
            plt.title('Epoch {} Loss'.format(e + 1))
            plt.xlabel('minibatch number')
            plt.ylabel('minibatch loss')
            plt.show()
    return total_loss, total_correct
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get stable results with TensorFlow, setting random seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed)

Comment: No i've seen that post and i've followed the way they have set the seed, but still i'm not able to get stable results

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using 3 different seedings? `np`, `tf` and `random`?

Comment: I understood that the results are not reproducible when using GPU. So it is not possible at all any ways thanks for your comments.