# Is the random state in tensorflow influenced by the graph structure?

Tags: tensorflow, random

By setting the random seed with `tf.set_random_seed(1234)`, I can repeat training runs exactly, so far so good. However, I noticed slight deviations when introducing extra variables in the graph. In the following example, `B` and `C` yield the exactly the same losses, but `A` gives something slightly (but not altogether) different. It's important to note that in version `C`, `intermediate_tensor` ist not attached to anything.

```
# version A:
output_tensor = input_tensor

# version B:
intermediate_tensor = input_tensor[..., :]
output_tensor = intermediate_tensor

# version C:
intermediate_tensor = input_tensor[..., :]
output_tensor = input_tensor
```

I would appreciate any insights, as I cannot explain this behaviour. Is it possible that the random number generator is somehow influenced by the graph content?

Answer (score 2):

> Operations that rely on a random seed actually derive it from two seeds: the graph-level and operation-level seeds. This sets the graph-level seed.
>
> If the graph-level seed is set, but the operation seed is not: The system deterministically picks an operation seed in conjunction with the graph-level seed so that it gets a unique random sequence.

Yes, the PRNG has an influence. A full description is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/faff6f2a60a01dba57cf3a3ab832279dbe174798/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/seed_stream.py#L24-L157) (Warning a long text to read!). The defaults for the seeds are [None](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f40a875355557483aeae60ffcf757fc9626c752b/tensorflow/python/framework/random_seed.py#L75). And if so they randomly [initialized afterwards](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cda36b817e9998906da37ec87c525f1b278c71a7/tensorflow/core/util/guarded_philox_random.cc#L38-L39)

```
seed = random::New64();
seed2 = random::New64();
```

And there is (guess what, a surprise) a Mersenne twister engine [behind](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cda36b817e9998906da37ec87c525f1b278c71a7/tensorflow/core/lib/random/random.cc#L34-L39).
For the GPU ops, they use then the `Philox algorithm` which is as well counter-based.

The same is also true when working on [datasets](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/83f1458ec1c19b3d46676ab543dff4ec401a0dd0/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/random_dataset_op.cc#L44-L45).

You should specify a per operation random seed to prevent all this random-stuff magic.

In summary, all additional random-ops nodes change the init-seeds. But in simple cases:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.set_random_seed(1234)

out1 = tf.random_normal([1])
out2 = tf.sqrt(tf.square(tf.random_normal([1])))
# out2 = tf.random_normal([1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run([out1, out2]))
```

The outputs are the same (commenting out/in `out2` above):

```
[array([-0.1386252], dtype=float32), array([-1.3978306], dtype=float32)]
[array([-0.1386252], dtype=float32), array([1.3978306], dtype=float32)]
```

If you want these reproducible runs within one session, please refer to

[Reproducible results in Tensorflow with tf.set_random_seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249811/reproducible-results-in-tensorflow-with-tf-set-random-seed/51252197#51252197)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for this elaborate answer. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51253945/2323484) answer, I found out that even non-random operations change the seeds for the following random operations, as the operation-level seeds are determined based on the ID of the previous operation.