# Not being able to reproduce the Same results over multiple runs for an LSTM model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reproducible-research

I was training an LSTM network in tensorflow. My model has the following configuration:

- time_steps = 1700
- Cell size: 120
- Number of input features x = 512.
- Batch size: 34
- Optimizer: AdamOptimizer with learning rate = 0.01
- Number of epochs = 20

I have GTX 1080 Ti. And my tensorflow version is 1.8.

Additionally, I have set the random seed through `tf.set_random_seed(mseed)`, and I have set the random seed for every trainable variable's initializer so that I can reproduce the same results after multiple runs.

After training the model multiple times, every time for 20 epochs, I found that I was achieving the same exact loss for the first several epochs (7, 8 or 9) "during each run", and then the loss start to differ. I was wondering why this is occuring; and if possible how can someone totally reproduce the results of any model.

Additionally, In my case I feeding the whole data during every iteration. That is, I have doing back propagation through time (BPTT) and not truncated BPTT. In other words, I have 2 iterations in total which is equal to the number of epochs as well.

The following figure demonstrate my problem. Please note that every row correspond to one epoch.

[image]

Please note that each column correspond to a different run. (I only included 2 columns/runs) to demonstrate my point.

Finally, replacing the input features with a new features of dimensions 100, I get better results as shown in the following image:

[image]

Therefore, I am not sure if this is a hardware issue or not?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

The likely issue, assuming everything you've done is correct, is [Adam is not reproducible](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12871#issuecomment-387927184) so that might be an issue.

But there are other potential sources of errors: [finalizing your graph and setting its seed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252197/3532564), and [operation level seeds](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed)

Hope this helps! It's hard to be sure everything you've done is correct without code but who knows how long your code might be

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, as you might have tried, `tf.set_random_seed(seed=1)` or `seed` equals any other integer number could be a possible solution.