# tf.set_random_seed doesn't seem to set the seed correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, random

I encountered a problem that `tf.set_random_seed` is unable to generate a repeatable value when programming using Tensorflow on python. To be specific,

```
import tensorflow as tf
sd = 1
tf.set_random_seed(seed = sd)

tf.reset_default_graph()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(tf.random_normal(shape=[1], mean=0, stddev=1)))
```

the code above outputs `[1.3086201]`. Then I ran the whole piece of code again, it doesn't outputs the expected value `[1.3086201]` but gives a new `[-2.1209881]`.

Why would this happen and how to set a Tensorflow seed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reproducible results in Tensorflow with tf.set\_random\_seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249811/reproducible-results-in-tensorflow-with-tf-set-random-seed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_random_seed), there are two types of seeds you can set when defining graph operations:

1. The graph-level seed, which is set by `tf.set_random_seed`, and
2. operation-level seeds which are placed in a variable initializer

Tensorflow then uses an elaborate set of rules (see the docs) to generate unique values for operations that rely on a seed. You can reproduce random output with a graph-level seed once you've initialized the variable, but **subsequent re-initializations of that variable will usually yield different values.**

In your code, you are re-initializing `tf.random_normal` each time you run your code, so it is different.

---

If you want `tf.random_normal` to generate the same unique sequence, no matter how many times it is re-initialized, you should **set the operation-level seed instead**,

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

print(sess.run(tf.random_normal(shape=[1], mean=0, stddev=1, seed=1))) 
# -0.8113182
print(sess.run(tf.random_normal(shape=[1], mean=0, stddev=1, seed=1)))
# -0.8113182
```

Comment: yet `tf.reset_default_graph()` clear the manual random seed in OP