# How can I ensure reproducibility in Tensorflow and Keras v2?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Google Colab, and I'm using `numpy.random.seed()` and `tensorflow.set_seed()` with Keras v2 and Tensorflow v2.x.

However, it still gives me different results in different runs. Is there anything else that I might need to set?

I specify an argument in both of them, I don't leave them without arguments.

```
np.random.seed(1) # this is in a notebook

... # this is a function called in the notebook

tf.random.set_seed(3)

self.model.fit_generator(
        random_cropper(datagen(X, Y)),
        steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
        epochs=EPOCHS,
        verbose=2,
        callbacks=callbacks
)
```

The output, which are the results for each epoch printed by `fit_generator` are not identical

Comment: Can you provide some example code of what you're trying and the output you're seeing?

Comment: @Tyler done, hope I gave you enough information

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy I don't know Colab, but if it is like in Jupyter, are the `numpy.random.seed()` in the same cell than the line you generate the numbers?

Comment: @Ben.T Yes, I call np.random.seed and then a function contained in a python file that contains the other lines, all in the same cell of the notebook

Comment: @NoImaginationGuy are the random number generated in the function from the python file?

Comment: @Ben.T yes, both randomness from numpy and tensorflow is extracted and used in the python file. Notebooks just call functions. Also let me point out that I don't explicitly extract randomness from tensorflow, I just call fit_generator which I'm assuming it is using tensorflow's random generator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting a specific number with the call to `numpy.random.seed()`? With no input, you are just reinitializing, but not specifying the seed ([source from Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html)). As [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed) says:

> If neither the global seed nor the operation seed is set: A randomly picked seed is used for this op

Try passing an integer into the function like `numpy.random.seed(42)` or similar `tensroflow.random.set_seed(42)`. (by the way, `tf.random.set_seed`, not `tf.set_seed`)

That will set the global seed. You will also want to set an operation seed for specific operations like `tensorflow.random.uniform([1], seed=1)`.

For more info, this question may be a duplicate of this other stackoverflow question: [Reproducible results in Tensorflow with tf.set_random_seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51249811/reproducible-results-in-tensorflow-with-tf-set-random-seed)

Comment: sorry, i will edit the question to specify this. Yes, I give it a number

Comment: the per-operation seed is interesting and useful, thanks. But the point is that I need to fix the seed for a fit_generator in Keras

Comment: This is not a simple problem. This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022950/which-seeds-have-to-be-set-where-to-realize-100-reproducibility-of-training-res has some explanation. There are all kinds of things that can lead to a degree of randomness in the process.