# In tensorflow why for a same dropout value of 0.8 when run with adam optimiser with 50epochs give different accuracy each time i run it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am building ANN as below:-

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(25,)))
model.add(Dense(25,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(5,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(xtraindata,ytraindata,epochs=50)
test_loss,test_acc=model.evaluate(xtestdata,ytestdata)
print(test_acc)
```

I am adding different features into the model and checking whether the newly added feature decreases or increases the accuracy but the problem is that each time I run this code with the same values I get different accuracy, sometimes it gets as low as 0.50 and so, I have few doubts and kindly answer them:-

1. Is the model giving different accuracy each time because in dropout reg. there are random dropouts in nodes and each time I run diff. nodes get silenced so thereby giving different accuracies i.e sometimes low and sometimes high?
2. How can I trust the accuracy of the model if each time it gives different accuracies? How can I know that the feature I have added has resulted in a decrement or increment of the accuracy?
3. If I get high accuracy and wanted to reproduce these results how do I save the parameters that the model has used?

Answer (score 0):

Great questions. Answers:

1. I think your theory is right; it's the dropout. That's the only layer with an element of randomness each run, so it's likely the culprit. Try removing that layer, leaving everything else fixed, and run multiple times. Check if the accuracy is the same.
2. Cross validation. This [article](https://medium.com/the-owl/k-fold-cross-validation-in-keras-3ec4a3a00538) explains how it works, but the gist is that it is a statistical technique that trains and checks the accuracy of multiple runs of your model, all with different slices of data. The average accuracy of all runs is used. So highs and lows will be averaged to a true(ish) accuracy. That being said, if your model has inconsistent results by just varying dropout, it's an indicator that when you move the model to production and use real data, it will perform poorly.
3. Keras api has a method `model.save("model_name")` to save models. You can use `keras.models.load_models("model_name")` to get it back. As I said in point 2 though; if your model is so finicky that some trainings drastically affect accuracy, then even if you train and get good accuracy, it probably won't be useful on new data. So when you say "If I get high accuracy and wanted to reproduce these results", really you shouldn't be thinking along these lines. Instead, try to get consistently high training accuracy.

Comment: Dropout is not the only element of randomness. Each layer is instantiated with the `glorot_uniform` kernel initializer, so unless a fixed seed is set, each run will have the model initialized with random kernels. More in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed