# set seed for entire model training/testing

Tags: tensorflow, random

I have a code using tensorflow v1 and I'd like to migrate it toward native tensorflow 2.
The code defines random objects (using `numpy.random`or `random`, a neural network (keras weight initialization etc) and other tensorflow's random functions. At the end, it makes predictions on a random test set and outputs loss/accuracy of the model.

For this task, I'm having the original code and a copy of it and I'm changing the code of the copy part by part. I want to make sure that the behaviour is the same so I want to set the randomness so that I can monitor if the loss/accuracy change

However, even after setting the seeds of the various random modules in my original file, launching it multiple times still give different loss/accuracy

here are my libraries :

```
import time
import random
import my_file as mf // file in directory scope
import numpy as np
import copy
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```

and I'm setting the seeds at the beginning like that :

```
tf.set_random_seed(42)
random.seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)
```

My module `my_file` uses the `random` library and I'm also setting the seed there

I do understand from the docs that `tf.set_random_seed` only sets the global seed and that each random operation in tensorflow is also using its own seed, resulting in different behaviors for consecutive calls. For example if I call the training/testing cell 3 times I get the consecutive value of losses L1 -> L2 -> L3
However, this should still result in the same behavior if I *restart* the environment so why isn't it the case ? If I restart the kernel and execute 3 times I will get L1' =/= L1 -> L2' =/= L2 -> L3' =/= L3

What else should I verify to make sure the behaviour is the same everytime I restart the notebook kernel ?

Comment: Related to [earlier SO question #36288235](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed), with 8 answers.

Comment: Thank you, the best answer worked. However, I just have a 10^-1 range error on the test losses and 10^-5 range errors on the test accuracy.
As suggested in the best answer, this may be because of floating point arithmetic.
Should I delete my post or should someone answer it by giving the original question ?

Comment: @AydinAbiar ! I think even if you use tf.random_set seed , you are going to get different values  because of usage of np.random or other tf.random . Can you please share a minimal reproducible code to investigate the issue though?