# Why can't repeat the training of a model with identical rsults?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to replicate the results of my model. But each time i run it, the results are different (even with restarting the google colab's runtime).
Here's the model

```
# set random seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)

# 1. Create the model
model_1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[1])
    ])

# 2. Compile the model
model_1.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
            metrics=["mae"])

# 3. Fit the model
model_1.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100)
```

`X_train` and `y_train` are two tensors each with `shape=(40,)`, and `dtype=int32`

```
# 4. make a prediction
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# 5. mean absolute error
mae = tf.metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_true=y_test,
                                     y_pred=tf.squeeze(tf.constant(y_pred)))
```

`X_test` and `y_test` are two tensors each with `shape=(10,)`, and `dtype=int32`

Now every time i run the above code i get a different value for `mae`, for example:
8.63, 21.26, 14.96, 14.93, 14,84, ...

I had expected to get identical runs, because i set the random seed before building and training the model.

How can i exactly reproduce my model's performance?

Comment: Please check if anything in the answers to this question solves the problem for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36288235/3005167

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Keras, there may be different seeds in play. This is documented [here](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/reproducibility_recipes/).

Keras has a function to set those seeds:

```py
# Set the seed using keras.utils.set_random_seed. This will set:
# 1) `numpy` seed
# 2) `tensorflow` random seed
# 3) `python` random seed
keras.utils.set_random_seed(812)
```

Maybe you'll also need to:

```py
# This will make TensorFlow ops as deterministic as possible, but it will
# affect the overall performance, so it's not enabled by default.
# `enable_op_determinism()` is introduced in TensorFlow 2.9.
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
```

Comment: I replaced ``tf.random.set_seed(42)`` with ``tf.keras.utils.set_random_ssed(42)`` and now i can reproduce the exact same results, Thanks